# How to remove Visual Studio solution from Git source control

Tags: git, visual-studio

By accident I added a new solution to Git source control by doing

> Right Click > Add to Source Control

on the solution. All my other solutions are under TFS.

For TFS controlled solution I can do

> File > Source Control > Advanced > Change Source Control

and Unbind.

I'd like to do same or similar thing with the Git project, but the File > Source Control option is missing in Visual Studio.

Comment: Just delete the ".git." directory at the root of the solution.  That all there is to it; everything that connects you to git is in that directory.  You may want to remove the ".gitignore" file at the root also (if it exists), but it won't affect anything to leave it. You may have to enable the "show hidden files" in Windows Explorer to see these files.

Comment: @BradleyUffner thanks that did it.

Comment: @Liam i did not even think to ask "how to fully delete git repository" because i did not know that is the issue here. two different questions can have the same answer. but that doesn't mean the questions are same. moreover different people can ask the same question in different ways. just my opinion.

Comment: @joym8 Please don't be offended by someone marking your question as a duplicate, it doesn't necessarily mean you did anything wrong.  It just helps us keep the site organized, so that 2 questions can have the same answer in just one place.  Your question will act as a sign-post to others seeking the same question, helping them find an answer.

Comment: @BradleyUffner oh ok sorry. i thought this question will be deleted. in which case people who arrived at my situation by doing what i did may not be able to find the answer. that was my only concern.

Comment: Most likely it will just be "closed", which simply stops others from adding additional answers to an already answered question.  If it is practically an *exact* duplicate, it may be deleted, but even that won't be counted against you.

Comment: Hi @joym8 you might want to have a read though [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) for more information